# Process.daemon vs. running a Ruby script with nohup + &

Tags: ruby, unix, daemons

I have a Ruby 1.9 script that I want to run as a long-running background process.

It looks like I have a choice between calling `Process.daemon` inside the script to daemonize it, or I can just run the script in the background using a shell's ampersand and keep it running after I log out of the server by prefixing the command with `nohup`.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Process.daemon` seems like a more clean and straightforward way, especially if this is something you would ever way to turn into a full-fledged daemon that is started during boot.